# minted is not working with Lyx but working with TeXstudio

Tags: errors, lyx, packages, texstudio, minted

As the title says: I have minted and pygments installed on my Macbook.
When I try to use `minted` in TeXstudio, all things work well, but with Lyx I inserted this TeX code into my document:

```
\begin{minted}{c}       
int main() {             
printf("hello, world");              
return 0; }  
\end{minted}
```

and I got this error message:

[image]

I had added `\usepackage{minted}` in the LaTeX preamble of my document.

I also exported my document in Lyx as a plain TeX and used it with TeXstudio without any problems.

Why can't LyX use minted like TeXstudio?

**Edit**: I forgot to mention that in both TeXstudio and LyX, I had added `-shell-escape`. In TeXstudio, here is how it appears:
[image]

and in LyX:
[image]

Comment: It seems LyX doesn't know how to fine the `pygmentize` program. Make sure that it is on your PATH, and maybe that will help.

Comment: I moved the folder `pygments` to `/Library/TeX/texbin` but to no avail.

Comment: That's no good. It's about the executable `pygmentize`. On my system it is `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pygmentize` (but then I have added `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin` to my PATH).

Comment: Yes. It worked. I copied `pygmentize` from `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/pygmen‌​tize` to  `Library/TeX/texbin`, and it worked after that. Thank you. Still remains one thing : _why LyX hadn't found it like TeXstudio had?_

Comment: @ammarx It’s generally not a good idea to copy/move executables around. They *may* appear to work but they may also fail (silently or noisily) because they don’t find themselves in the place they expect to be. It’s better to adjust your path configuration or (if needed) to create symlinks.

Comment: Did you run Tools>Reconfigure and restart Lyx? It's possible it just never thought to see if Minted was installed in the first place.